# If $f(x) = g(x)|h(x)|$ and $h(x_0)=0$, then what is the condition for $f$ to be differentiable in $x_0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The functions $g$ and $h$ are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. The function $f$ is:

$$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{2cm} f(x)=g(x)|h(x)|$$

If we know that $h(x_0) = 0$, then what is the condition for the function $f$ to be differentiable at the point $x_0$? I have to choose between $5$ possible answers:

**A.** $h'(x_0)=0$

**B.** $g(x_0) > 0$

**C.** $g(x_0)=0$

**D.** $g(x_0)h'(x_0)=0$

**E.** Other answer

How should I approach this?

Comment: Make some efforts here. What do you know about the absolute value and differentiability? Have you tried some examples?

Comment: @TedShifrin Well, I know that since $h(x_0) = 0$ that means that the function $|h(x)|$ is **not** differentiable at $x_0$. What kind of examples should I try? I know it looks like I want someone else to solve the problem for me top to bottom, but I really don't know how to even start solving this. Can you please tell me what to look for? What should I consider? What examples should I try and what would they tell me?

Comment: Well, compare $|x|$ and $|x|^{3/2}$.